# Show that $(A\cap B)^c = (A^c \cap B) \cup (A^c \cap B^c) \cup (A \cap B^c)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It is given that $\;A^c = (A^c \cap B) \cup (A^c \cap B^c),\;$ and $\;B^c = (A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B^c)$

Therefore we have,
$$(A\cap B)^c = A^c \cup B^c = ((A^c \cap B) \cup (A^c \cap B^c)) \cup ((A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B^c))$$

But I'm not sure how this leads to $(A^c \cap B) \cup (A^c \cap B^c) \cup (A \cap B^c)$.

As far as I can tell, it would be $(A^c \cap B) \cup 2(A^c \cap B^c) \cup (A \cap B^c)$.

What am I not seeing?

Comment: $X\cup X=X$, so $(A^c\cap B^c)\cup(A^c\cap B^c)=A^c\cap B^c$

Comment: You are confused. What you appear to be asserting is that for $A$ a set, $A \cup A = 2A$. But what is $2A$? Does this have a well defined meaning to you, when $A$ is a set? It might do, but it's probably not $A \cup A$. I'm sure you can see your mistake now, from the answer which amWhy has given, but it might be helpful for you to go back and check the precise definition of the union of two sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highlighted sets below are the same set:

\begin{align} (A\cap B)^c &= A^c \cup B^c \tag{DeMorgan's}\\ \\ &= ((A^c \cap B) \cup \color{blue}{(A^c \cap B^c)}) \cup ((A \cap B^c) \cup \color{blue}{(A^c \cap B^c)})\\ \\ &= (A^c\cap B) \cup \color{blue}{(A^c \cap B^c)}\cup \color{blue}{(A^c \cap B^c)} \cup (A\cap B^c)\tag{*}\end{align}

We need only count a set once; afterall, given any set $C,\;\,C\cup C = C.$     In this case we have $$(A^c \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B^c) = A^c\cap B^c.$$

Hence, we arrive at 
$$(A\cap B)^c = A^c \cup B^c = (A^c \cap B)  \cup (A \cap B^c) \cup (A^c \cap B^c).$$

$(*)$  We used the associative property and the commutative property of set-union: $\cup$.

---

Note:  By the definition of the intersection of two sets, e.g. $A^c\cap B^c$, we have that $$A^c \cap B^c = \{x\mid x \not\in A \land x \not\in B\}.$$

Just because we see $A^c \cap B^c$ appear twice in your expansion, there is no need to repeat the fact that $A^c\cap B^c = \{x\mid x\notin A \land x\notin B\}$.

They both refer to one set of elements: those that are not in A and those that are not in B. Hence, we can simplify by mentioning it only once.

Comment: Why didn't you want to be a moderator? +